# Substituir parte do ID, Name e Class de um input

Tags: jquery

**Tenho os seguintes inputs**

```
<div class="sub-item-rows" id="pega-id">

  <input class="numeric_only left addon_qty_limitador disabled" style="border:none; background-color:unset" maxlength="5" type="text" value="1" name="addon_qty_limitador[13][0]" id="addon_qty_limitador_13_0" disabled="disabled">
  <input class="numeric_only left addon_qty_limitador disabled" style="border:none; background-color:unset" maxlength="5" type="text" value="1" name="addon_qty_limitador[14][0]" id="addon_qty_limitador_14_0" disabled="disabled">
  <input class="numeric_only left addon_qty_limitador disabled" style="border:none; background-color:unset" maxlength="5" type="text" value="1" name="addon_qty_limitador[15][0]" id="addon_qty_limitador_15_0" disabled="disabled">   

  <input style="padding: 13px; border-radius:20px" type="submit" value="adicionar ao carrinho" class="add_to_cart green-button upper-text">
</div>
```

**E a seguinte função em Jquery:**

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".add_to_cart", function() {        

     //Aqui preciso remover de todos os inputs o text _limitador
       form_submit('frm-fooditem');
   });
```

A função captura o click do botão, dentro dessa ação preciso verificar todos os inputs que possuem o no atributo name o texto **_limitador** e remover esse texto do Name, ID e Class.

**Com os dados de exemplo, ao clicar no botão o código deveria ficar:**

```
<div class="sub-item-rows" id="pega-id">

  <input class="numeric_only left addon_qty disabled" style="border:none; background-color:unset" maxlength="5" type="text" value="1" name="addon_qty[13][0]" id="addon_qty_13_0" disabled="disabled">
  <input class="numeric_only left addon_qty disabled" style="border:none; background-color:unset" maxlength="5" type="text" value="1" name="addon_qty[14][0]" id="addon_qty_14_0" disabled="disabled">
  <input class="numeric_only left addon_qty disabled" style="border:none; background-color:unset" maxlength="5" type="text" value="1" name="addon_qty[15][0]" id="addon_qty_15_0" disabled="disabled">   

  <input style="padding: 13px; border-radius:20px" type="submit" value="adicionar ao carrinho" class="add_to_cart green-button upper-text">
</div>
```

Comment: Basta utilizar o `String.prototype.replace`. Você irá "repor" o `_limitador` por uma string vazia.

Comment: desculpe mas não consigo perceber bem pq precisou gerar o id e name com "_limitador" pra depois remover, era mais fácil gerar o elemento como deve ser, e mudar só a classe por exemplo. Não é uma pratica comum mudar Id e Name dos elementos, geralmente se remove/adiciona o elemento todo, mas pode fazer um loop nos elementos e usar replace, como @LuizFelipe comentou, mas isso vai bagunçar o DOM, use o `attr` ou `prop` do `jquery` para evitar isso